# Access data generated in one docker container in another one

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to run a few docker containers using `docker-compose.yml`. Each docker container has an entrypoint, where it creates the config file for the process. I can't change the process itself (I have only the executable file), only it's configuration.

The first container is a "master". It generates keys, and the others need to have this keys in their configuration.

How can I pass the generated keys from the "master" to the other containers? I could use shared volume, but maybe there is some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shared volume is really the best way and the most common solution to this problem.  Define the volume in your `docker-compose.yml` and then  mount it at a common location in each container. Something like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  foo:
    image: service/foo
    volumes:
      - "config:/config"

  bar:
    image: service/bar
    volumes:
      - "config:/config"

volumes:
  config:
```